# collocation with a word stress

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, verbs, collocations

This is my question.

- **feel** stress
- **have** stress
- **receive** stress
- **get** stress

which collocation is best fit for a word *stress*? (particularly in academic writing)

and if there are any awkward collocation, please let me know

Comment: "have stress" seems the one I'd be most likely to use in speech (I would never say "receive stress" or "get stress"), but I wouldn't use any of these in academic writing. Have you tried "experience stress"?

Comment: @Sparksbet I have to use collocation 'stress' in academic version... thus I looked up some grammar book in my country(Korea), and I found four possible collocations as I wrote in the question..

Comment: I think that Sparksbet is right, "experience stress" sounds more academic than your four choices.

Comment: Perhaps we need more context to understand what exactly is meant by **academic** here.

Comment: This question came back around. I wonder why.

Comment: get, have and receive do not collocate with stress, generally speaking.

Answer (score 1):

The best option here may not be in your list - it is very common to describe someone (or something) as being *under* stress.

If you do need to use one of the 4 options you listed, I believe the most appropriate would be to *feel* stress, assuming that you are using stress in the context of a human (i.e. not stress on a material or object, such as a bridge). Stress can be defined as a feeling of emotional or mental pressure, therefore feeling fits well.

Answer (score 0):

The most common form is: **to be stressed.**

In academic or any other type of formal writing.

Unless there is a specific reason for it, use the verb form.

Otherwise, one can feel stress, yes. The other verbs don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- have stress
- experience stress
- be under stress
- suffer from stress